# Detection issue of usb tuner to Android phone

Tags: java, android, c++

My USB Tuner DVB-T2 is not detected in my Android phone. I have followed the steps as mentioned in the data sheet. I downloaded air dv II app in my phone.
Still it is not recognizing it is telling that device is not found.

What should I do?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and edit you question with more detail as to how this is a programming problem. As right now no one can help you as there isn't enough detail such as which phone and which USB tuner you are tried to connect.

Comment: I connected to every phone but  I could not find where the problem is and the usb tuner is DVB T2

Comment: `DVB T2` is a specification not a device. You are better off going back directly to the manufacturer for questions.

Comment: ok thanks for responding